Декоратор для удаления предыдущего сообщения Telebot
Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста, написать декоратор, который бы удалял предыдущие сообщения.
Есть функция:
def func(call, bot):
    bot.send_message(
        call.from_user.id,
        "Привет!",
        reply_markup=button()
    )

И вот эту строчку перед bot.send_message должен добавлять декоратор:
bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id)


Если я вас правильно понял:
def decorator_delete_message(func):
    def wrapper(call, bot):
        bot.delete_message(call.from_user.id, call.message.message_id)
        return func(call, bot)
    return wrapper

@decorator_delete_message
def my_func(call, bot):
    bot.send_message(call.from_user.id,"Привет!",reply_markup=button())

